# Looking for a guide on oauth2resttemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta

Iam trying to implement an oauth2 client for my application. I am able to get it working with RestTemplate by generating the token and adding that to the bearer header programmatically. Then I found the oauth2RestTemplate which seems more convenient. But I am not able to find a good example. I am also looking if I can do the token recreation on expiry to happen. Can you please help me how to implement it. I have client ID, client secret and token generation URL.

Comment: Note that `OAuth2RestTemplate` is part of the deprecated spring-security-oauth module. Please ensure you are using a supported version of Spring Security. You can see the new approach for using `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` in the [OAuth 2.0 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide#a-simplified-resttemplate-and-webclient).